# Does dplyr `is_grouped_df()` actually require a date frame (vs a data table, tibble, etc.)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping, tibble

Does the dplyr function `is_grouped_df()` actually require the input to be a date frame (vs a data table, tibble, etc.)? If it does not require a data frame why isn't it named `is_grouped` instead of `is_grouped_df`?

---

#### #1 - mtcars with multiple classes

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% is_grouped_df()
#> [1] TRUE

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% class()
#> [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I can group a multiple class mtcars data set, and confirm with the `is_grouped_df()` function that the data set is grouped.

---

#### #2 - mtcars as a tibble

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% as_tibble() %>% is_grouped_df()
#> [1] FALSE

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% as_tibble() %>% class()
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I can try to force mtcars to be a tibble and notice that when I check if it is a `is_grouped_df` I get FALSE as the answer. Even though that doesn't seem to be the case. I never called the `ungroup()` function in my pipe after grouping. Why FALSE?

---

#### #3 - mtcars as a data frame (an attempt to return to #1)

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% as_tibble() %>% as.data.frame() %>% is_grouped_df()
#> [1] FALSE

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% as_tibble() %>% as.data.frame() %>% class()
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

I can try to force mtcars to be a data frame and notice that when I check if it is a `is_grouped_df` I get FALSE as the answer. Even though that doesn't seem to be the case. I never called the `ungroup()` function in my pipe after grouping. Why FALSE?

---

And now I circle back to the original question, "*Does the dplyr function is_grouped_df() actually require the input to be a date frame (vs a data table, tibble, etc.)?*". And why all the inconsistencies in my three examples above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you add the `as_tibble` or `as.data.frame` functions, the groups that were created by the `group_by` function are deleted.

You can't create groups on a data frame. The data frame is converted to a tibble as soon as you use `group_by`

```
class(mtcars)
[1] "data.frame"

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    class()
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

You can see how the data frame gets converted into a tibble by using `group_by`

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl)
# A tibble: 32 x 11
# Groups:   cyl [3]
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

But as soon as you call `as_tibble` again, the groups dissapear.

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    as_tibble()
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Same thing happens if you call `as.data.frame` after using `group_by`

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

So basically, `is_grouped_df` works as intended, only detecting tibbles that have groups. In this case, it's important to note that `as_tibble` will effectively reset the groups that have already been created, so it ends up acting as `ungroup` if called on a tibble.

Comment: There was one extra question:  "why isn't it named `is_grouped` instead of `is_grouped_df`?"  That's answered by the result in your first code chunk:  the class name is `"grouped_df"`, and the function tests for that class.